# How to change theme in Magento 2.1rc3?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento-2.1

I tried both `Magento v2.1rc3` and `Magento2` develop version from git repository.

Problem is that when I tried to change `Magento 2` theme, I followed below steps:

---

```
Open BO -> Stores -> Configurations -> General -> Design
```

---

And I don't see "**Design Theme**" section with theme select `dropdown` anymore.

I tried to look deeper in this and found that node with this configuration was removed from `system.xml(Magento\Backend module)`. I found commit with removing this node in history  of Magento2 git repository and it has have message "**Remove old code.**"

So, I hope this `configuration` was moved to some another place in Back Office of Magento. But I don't found it in any of the `system.xml` files. Maybe someone know why it was done and in what way I can change my Magento 2 theme?

Answer (score 14):

It seems the theme configuration was moved.

It can be found in main administration menu:

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

Click on scope you are interested in(probably the first one) and change 'Applied theme'.